# how do I format an entire column (or cells I can iterate thru)as text format using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need help with how to change excel columns to text before the python script copies them from one file to another file

currently using openpyxl....
but open to any library that does the job and doesnt lose any of the other formatting or coloring in the worksheets

the problem is, when something has a date in it, I need it to copy as straight text, and not as a date

so when somebody has typed 6/17/2019... its stays as EXACTLY that
instead of getting changed into something like 2019-06-17 0:00:00

I *think* the right place to do it would be right after I load each workbook.
I know if I manually change the files so that the columns needed are formatted as "text", the script works perfect and everything copies as intended.

I'm looking for a function in openpyxl that is teh same thing as right clicking the cell in excel, selecting formatting, and choosing "text"

```
# open both files, load them in, 
#Change Columns F and H to Text Formatting before doing the next part of the script







#Begin Openpyxl Section

orig_wb = load_workbook('old_qc_report.xlsx')
new_wb = load_workbook('new_qc_report.xlsx')


sheetlist = orig_wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet = orig_wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetlist[0])
sheetlist2 = new_wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet2 = new_wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetlist[0])


s1rownumber = 1
for s1row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row= sheet.max_row, min_col=6, max_col=6, values_only=True):
  s1rownumber +=1
  for cell in s1row:
    if cell != None:
#      print(cell)
      transfer_cust_rec = cell
      product_description_ref = sheet[str("A" + str(s1rownumber))].value
      order_No_ref = sheet[str("C" + str(s1rownumber))].value
#      print(product_description_ref)
#      print(order_No_ref)

      s2rownumber = 1
      for s2row in sheet2.iter_rows(min_row = 2, min_col=1, max_col=1, values_only=True):
        s2rownumber +=1
        for cell2 in s2row:
          if cell2 == product_description_ref:
            if sheet2[str("C" + str(s2rownumber))].value == order_No_ref:
              sheet2[str("F" + str(s2rownumber))].value = transfer_cust_rec


s1rownumber = 1
for s1row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row= sheet.max_row, min_col=8, max_col=8, values_only=True):
  s1rownumber +=1
  for cell in s1row:
    if cell != None:
#      print(cell)
      transfer_notes = cell
      product_description_ref = sheet[str("A" + str(s1rownumber))].value
      order_No_ref = sheet[str("C" + str(s1rownumber))].value
#      print(product_description_ref)
#      print(order_No_ref)

      s2rownumber = 1
      for s2row in sheet2.iter_rows(min_row = 2, min_col=1, max_col=1, values_only=True):
        s2rownumber +=1
        for cell2 in s2row:
          if cell2 == product_description_ref:
            if sheet2[str("C" + str(s2rownumber))].value == order_No_ref:
              sheet2[str("H" + str(s2rownumber))].value = transfer_notes


new_wb.save(outfilepath)


wb.close

os.remove("old_qc_report.xlsx")
os.remove("new_qc_report.xlsx")

print("\nThis program took %2.3f seconds to run\n"%(time.time() - start_time))
time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *with only OpenPyXL*

---

Since you want to keep this format *after* saving the Excel file --not just during OpenPyXL edition, use number format as `'@'`

```
    import openpyxl

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            # only relevant column and without header
            if cell.column_letter == 'D' and cell.row > 1:
                ws[cell.coordinate].number_format = '@'

    wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

output

[image]

Hope it helps (:

Comment: if you prefer the code with your own example, please provide some outputs so it can be possible to reproduce. meanwhile, use the code provided to adapt it to your project

Comment: the problem I'm finding with pandas is that its creating a dataframe, which strips all the other things I need to keep.

there are coloring's and Bold's and column sizing's that I need to preserve from where I am at in the script already.

Comment: Just did a test... Cant use Pandas.
`Pandas Destroys everything already done and spits it out in a format that shifts everything...`

Comment: I know there is a function in openpyxl... Just teh documentation sucks and I cant figure out how to use it.....
`Documentation shows me using styles and "FORMAT_TEXT"... but no explanation of how or where to use it`

Comment: hmm... understood. try `datetime.strptime(str(ws[cell.coordinate].value), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`. I will update the answer with only OpenPyXL

Comment: its not necessarily a date
the column can have a date typed in it, or possibly words like "shows up tuesday"
so I need to be able to format the cell as "text"

Comment: There is no need to use `ws[cell.coordinate]` as this will return the cell itself. For programmatic access for cells there are other easier and preferable methods available.

Comment: @soundtechscott I've updated the answer with [.]._ = '@' that is what makes the trick when passing the parameter to _ method to say that your number is a  (◔_◔)